# Laptop heats up when I start/use PhpStorm IDE

Tags: laptop, php, overheating, text-editor, heat

I looked at similar questions but it didnt work.

When I use laptop normally, it doesnt heat up.
But it heats up when I start/use PhpStorm IDE.

What can be the issue, how to overcome it ? Thanks.

Comment: PhpStorm uses a **lot** of resources, sometimes it uses up two of my four CPU cores. High CPU usage = more heat. And I doubt you can do anything against that.

Comment: @the_Seppi, please be optimist. I hope some one will answer it for sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of resource usage that generates the heat.  As alluded to in comments, PhpStorm takes a lot of resources and CPU usage.  This in turn means your CPU needs to run and generate heat (as a byproduct) to process the requirements.  This is a side effect of resource-intense programs, and unfortunately there's no good solutions to this problem.  (Windows is plagued by the same problem too)

Short of manually throttling your CPU power (which would impact overall performance of the system and maybe make PhpStorm not work), there's no real way to overcome this issue.

Comment: So you mean there is no real solution?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Correct.  Either use a less resource intensive program/IDE, or rate limit your processor (affects globally) or do nothing.  Alternatively, invest $10-$20 for a laptop cooling pad with fans that can increase airflow to the bottom of the computer (and help a little with getting hot air away from the system; note that this option is exactly what I do and my laptop doesn't overheat and I didn't have to change anything on the system at all except to sacrifice one USB port).